# Permutations of List by Swapping 2 Values

Tags: c#, permutation

I have a list which contains information on a Part:

```cs
List<Part> partList = new List<Part>
{
    new Part
    {
        Length = 150,
        Width = 100
    },
    new Part
    {
        Length = 300,
        Width = 50,
    },
    new Part
    {
        Length = 100,
        Width = 50,
    },
};
```

And what I want from this is permutations which get all combinations of Length x Width for each Part.

Example:

```cs
List<Part> x = new List<Part>
{
    new Part
    {
        Length = 100,
        Width = 150
    },
    new Part
    {
        Length = 300,
        Width = 50,
    },
    new Part
    {
        Length = 100,
        Width = 50,
    },
};

List<Part> n = new List<Part>
{
    new Part
    {
        Length = 150,
        Width = 100
    },
    new Part
    {
        Length = 50,
        Width = 300,
    },
    new Part
    {
        Length = 100,
        Width = 50,
    },
};
```

And it essentially swaps all the lengths and widths within each Part and gets all the combinations for this.

Comment: Have you had any attempts at this yourself? If so please post that code. What are the exact issues you ran into?

Comment: @Etheraex I have code for standard permutations, but with this problem I honestly have no idea where to even start which is why I'm hoping to get some direction here. I've been reading lots of different answers for different problems for a few hours

Comment: Lets see if this helps, you want to go over all of the elements of your original array of Parts and for each `Part` generate a new `Part` object with the values for `Length` and `Width` swapped. Then just add that new object to some new array which is empty in the beginning.

Comment: @Etheraex I've done that part, but what I'm struggling with is after I swap the first Part, how does the next iteration know that it must swap 1 and 2, then 1 and 3, then 2 and 3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I know it can be simplified a lot, but it works for what I need. Feel free to post any modifications.

```
public List<List<Part>> RotatePartList(List<Part> partList, List<List<Part>> rotatedList, int initialCounter = 0, int position = 0, int secondCounter = 1)
        {
            List<Part> tempPartList = new List<Part>();
            foreach (var part in partList)
            {
                tempPartList.Add(new Part
                {
                    Label = part.Label,
                    Length = part.Length,
                    Width = part.Width
                });
            }

            // Swap only one of each number (i.e. The first number is swapped, then the second, then the third etc.)
            if (initialCounter <= partList.Count() - 1)
            {
                tempPartList[initialCounter].Length = partList[initialCounter].Width;
                tempPartList[initialCounter].Width = partList[initialCounter].Length;
                rotatedList.Add(tempPartList);
                RotatePartList(partList, rotatedList, initialCounter + 1);
            }

            // Only run this if there are more than 2 parts
            if (partList.Count() > 2)
            {
                // Swap each item and everything ahead of it one at a time (i.e swap the first item and second, then first and third, then first and fourth etc.)
                if (position != partList.Count() - 1)
                {
                    if (secondCounter <= partList.Count() - 1)
                    {
                        tempPartList[position].Length = partList[position].Width;
                        tempPartList[position].Width = partList[position].Length;

                        tempPartList[secondCounter].Length = partList[secondCounter].Width;
                        tempPartList[secondCounter].Width = partList[secondCounter].Length;

                        rotatedList.Add(tempPartList);

                        RotatePartList(partList, rotatedList, initialCounter, position, secondCounter + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {   // The current item and all the ones ahead have been swapped one at a time, so go to next item
                        position += 1;
                        secondCounter = position + 1;
                        RotatePartList(partList, rotatedList, initialCounter, position, secondCounter);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If all values have been swapped, add the original list and the one where ALL items are swapped
            rotatedList.Add(partList);

            if (partList.Count() > 1)
            { 
                for (var i = 0; i <= partList.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    tempPartList[i].Length = partList[i].Width;
                    tempPartList[i].Width = partList[i].Length;
                }
                rotatedList.Add(tempPartList);
            }

            return rotatedList;
        }
```

My solution is to swap one **Part** at a time, then swap the Part at index 1 and every Part ahead of it one at a time (i.e. index 1 and 2, then 1 and 3, then 1 and 4 etc.) Before moving onto index 2 and doing the same forward rotation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you only need to extract available widths ans lengths and then enumerate all possible combinations:

```csharp
public List<Part> GetPerumatations(IReadOnlyList<Part> parts)
{
    // get all possible distinct length (that are actually the width because you need to swap L&W)
    var lengths = parts.Select(p => p.Width).Distinct().ToArray();

    // same for widths
    var widths = parts.Select(p => p.Length).Distinct().ToArray();

    var result = new List<Part>();
    foreach (var length in lengths)
    foreach (var width in widths)
    {
        result.Add(new Part { Width = width, Length = length });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't focus on time complexity (the code will has n*n recursively), it can be solved using a simple approach like this:

```
PROCEDURE CombinateAttributes(lastIndex, lengthOfList) BEGIN
    IF lastIndex==-1 BEGIN return END
    FOR i=lastIndex TO i<lengthOfList BEGIN
        partList[i].Length, partList[i].Width = partList[i].Width, partList[i].Length
    END
    CombinateAttributes(lastIndex-1, lengthOfList)
END
```

You can easy understand the structure in the case that you have used or saw password (or keyword) generators in most GNU/Linux distributions. They generally use this basic algorithm.

Please don't forget to pass the length of the partList as arguments, and take values from FOR section if you like to store a combination. You can call this procedure like that:

```
CombinateAttributes(len(partList), len(partList))
```

Comment: Thank you bro, I've already come up with a solution and it is very similar to this. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Not even C# ...

Comment: @Orace lol... ^_^

Answer (score -1):

I will give my solution:

With n part you can have 2^n cases, accordingly, let's do it:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 2^n; i++)
{
    //do something
}
```

For each case, you can transpose one or more parts, so by converting int to binary, we get all of those combinations.

Example,

with 0, binary is `000` (bit length is n), no swap

with 1, binary is `001` (bit length is n), swap will be Part at position 3

with 2, binary is `010` (bit length is n), swap will be Part at position 2

...

with 7, binary is `111` (bit length is n), swap will be Part in all positions

Comment: Impressively fully useful!